# Letterspace all caps in document

Tags: spacing, fontspec, letterspacing, titlecaps

How does one letterspace all uppercase letters in a document?

I can achieve this for small caps with `fontspec`:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures = {LetterSpace = 7.5}]{Warnock Pro}
```

but what about normal caps? I know I can define a new command, but how will I letterspace headings then?

Haven't found a setting in `fontspec`'s manual. Is there one?

Answer (score 7):

You have to mark the place where spaced capitals are desired:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}[
  SmallCapsFeatures={LetterSpace=7.5}
]

\NewDocumentCommand{\allcaps}{m}{%
  {\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=7.5}#1}%
}

\begin{document}

Normal text to see what happens

\textsc{This is spaced Small Caps}

\allcaps{THIS IS SPACED ALL CAPS}

THIS IS UNSPACED ALL CAPS

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But how do I apply this to `\section{Heading}` that my chosen class (`memoir` + `\headstyles{dowding}`) sets in caps?